# Setting explicit command to run SFTP server in FileZilla client (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, ssh, sftp, filezilla, winscp

Basically what I am looking forward is the same functionality on Mac OS as the WinSCP screenshot below

[image: Screenshot from WinSCP]

I have SSH tunnel application to establish tunnel with the server and using the FileZilla for transfer. Using FileZilla I could access the server but I still cannot write/copy the files to server. What I need is to achieve the same setting as the one showing in WinSCP screenshot. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FileZilla does not have any option equivalent to *[SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_sftp)* in WinSCP.

You can [run WinSCP under Wine on OSX](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/requirements#client).